# Error 500 in new extensions installed (Joomla 3.0 Gantry Framework & Magnus tmpl)

Tags: joomla-3.x, gantry

On a page developed with Joomla 3.0, Gantry Framework & Magnus Template everything has been running fine but when installing new extensions like rs_mediagallery , facegallery or rokgallery , the installation finishs well but then when trying to access the component to configure (ie: Components --> Rsmediagallery) it shows a blank page and firebug indicates an error " 500 Internal Server Error".

All the site is running well including another extensions already installed.

tmp and extension directories have the correct permissions.

If someone has an idea in order to solve this error, I thanks

Campo

Comment: Try first uninstall and then re-install the extensions.

Comment: Can you set `error reporting` to "Development" (go to **Global Configuration** -> **Server tab** -> **Error Reporting**). If you see any error messages, please add them to your question.

Comment: Yes. I set Global Configuration -> Server tab -> Error Reporting to Development and Maximum with identical results.

Comment: I will uninstall then install this extension wirth error reporting = development in order to see if this ext is installed in the right way.

Comment: OK. Uninstall was Ok. But when i tried to install this ext again, it shows the following msg: "An error has occurred.     -1 Copy file failed". This msg must be related to directory permissions because a moved this app to a new folder. I'll check permision in order to try again.

Comment: The above error occurred because directorypermissions. It was corrected. Then when I installed the extension with error_reporting = development again, the system says it successfully installed but if the component is running, it displays a blank page without any message.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest getting your error log from the cpanel to see the problem. 500 errors are usually server side error. It might be you're installing on an unsupported version of PHP or a permission issue.

Answer (score 1):

mod_security can sometimes cause this type of behaviour.

Check with your hosting provider explaining the exact steps that cause the error or you may be able to temporarily disable mod_security by adding the following to `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```