# After updating to Joomla 3.6.0, I cannot install a new extension

Tags: joomla-3.6

After updating to version 3.6.0, I wanted to install a new extension, but I got this warning message:

> No installation plugin has been enabled. At least one must be enabled to be able to use the installer. Go to the Plugin Manager to enable the plugins.

But there is no installer plugin in my plugin manager. How to solve the issue?

Comment: I tried all the steps above and it is still not working. I get an error message after attempting an install from the web tab or Upload package file... HTTP SERVER 500 Error Any idea what is wrong and how to fix it? Thanks[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClPUq.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClPUq.jpg)

Comment: Actually "server error 500" is out of the scope of this question. If you cannot find a proper answer by search, please click on "Ask Question" and fill the form with detailed information. BTW, [joomla.stackexchange.com/q/4963/1520](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/4963/1520) may help.

Answer (score 7):

The steps are:

1. Go to `Extensions` > `Manage` > `Discover`
2. Click on <kbd>Discover</kbd> button. Now you can see 3 installer plugins:

   - Installer - Install from Folder
   - Installer - Install from URL
   - Installer - Install from Upload
3. Check all the checkboxes or at least `Installer - Install from Upload` checkbox and then click on <kbd>Install</kbd> button.
4. Go to `Extensions` > `Plugins` and enable the Installer plugins.
5. Now you can install extensions by going to `Extensions` > `Manage` > `Install`

[image]

That's it.